# Nice way of tweening CCLabelTTF?

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, cclabelttf

Is there something to tween the font size `CCLabelTTF` in a nice way?
I guess using `CCScaleTo` does not really recreate the font every iteration now does it?

Comment: Define your question in brief.

Comment: it doesn't because that would be costly (like changingthe label's string)

Comment: Ok. I just do a CCScaleTo and when done recreate the font with size scaled down. If the scale duration is short and quick enough no one will notice and I can get on with life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ("nice") way of tweening CCLabelTTF, as per the answer of LearnCocos2D.

So what I did, I just scale the rasterized version and on scale done I recreate it with font size scaled same, and also scale the node itself to 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

```
[label setFontSize:newFontSize];
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this inside an animation?

Comment: what do you mean by inside animation?